# How to calculate "A" in R's fastSOM package?

Tags: r, covariance-matrix

I'm very new to R and need to calculate some things for my thesis with the fastSOM package.
I already created the necessary cov matrix (4x4 matrix). 
Now to run the calculation for the spillovers, I need a variable "A". 
As stated in the package description, A has to be "Either a 3-dimensional array with A[„h] being MA coefficient matrices of the same dimension as Sigma or a list thereof."

That's the point where I am stuck since I have little clue how to create this A for my given problem.

I hope someone can help me out here.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Post code that creates a valid example. Look up “how to make a great reproducible example in R”

Comment: The code for an easy example is:
N <- 10
Sigma <- crossprod(matrix(rnorm(N*N),nrow=N))
H <- 10
A <- array(rnorm(N*N*H),dim=c(N,N,H))
soi(Sigma,A)

In my case, I created Sigma as a covariance matrix of stock returns on different financial markets over 3 years. Now I stuck in creating the corresponding A

Comment: Are you sure that will deliver a valid covariance matrix? My memory is that they need to be symmetric and positive-definite. Also do NOT use comments do deliver code.  See [ask]

Comment: You may want to take a look at [Spillover package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Spillover/), a userfriendly version for estimating connectedness index proposed in Diebold and Yilmaz (2009, 2012)